# sql double multiple column key

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

Its an Sql query.

I want to know duplicate data.

Sample:

```
Table 1
Col1, col2, col3, col4
1, A, AA, AAA
2, A, BB, AAA
3, A, BB, AAA
4, B, AA, AAA
5, B, AA, BBB
6, B, AA, CCC
7, B, BB, AAA
8, B, CC, AAA
```

the result should be :

```
2, A, BB, AAA
3, A, BB, AAA
```

Or

```
A, BB, AAA
```

So I can found where's my doubles.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also do it like this:

**Test data**

```
DECLARE @T TABLE(Col1 int, col2 VARCHAR(100), col3 VARCHAR(100), 
                 col4 VARCHAR(100))

INSERT INTO @T
VALUES
    (1, 'A', 'AA', 'AAA'),
    (2, 'A', 'BB', 'AAA'),
    (3, 'A', 'BB', 'AAA'),
    (4, 'B', 'AA', 'AAA'),
    (5, 'B', 'AA', 'BBB'),
    (6, 'B', 'AA', 'CCC'),
    (7, 'B', 'BB', 'AAA'),
    (8, 'B', 'CC', 'AAA')
```

**Query1**

```
;WITH CTE
AS
(   
    SELECT
        COUNT(Col1) OVER(PARTITION BY col2,col3,col4) AS Counts,
        T.*
    FROM
        @T AS T
)
SELECT
    *
FROM
    CTE
WHERE
    Counts>1
```

**Result**

```
2   2   A   BB  AAA
2   3   A   BB  AAA
```

**Query2**

```
;WITH CTE
AS
(   
    SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY col2,col3,col4 ORDER BY col1) AS RowNbr,
        T.*
    FROM
        @T AS T
)
SELECT
    *
FROM
    CTE
WHERE
    CTE.RowNbr>1
```

**Result**

```
2   3   A   BB  AAA
```

Comment: No problem. @forX Remember to upvote the answer you think are good. That gives us all a warm fuzzy feeling :P

Answer (score 2):

You can group by the columns and check whether there is more than 1 record for each group:

```
select
    col2, col3, col4
from
    MyTable
group by
    col2, col3, col4
having
    count(*) > 1
```

Demo: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5c3a7/2